# Why do the part code chunks run without display the result?

Tags: r, r-markdown

```r
library(dplyr)
data_group<- group_by(D_Fish, `Sample Location`)
data_GroupByID<- summarise(data_group,count = n())
data_GroupByID
```

[image: After running the chunk, there is no output in line or Console.]

Comment: Try ```r{ echo =T}
...
```

Comment: Or close the chunk with ```.